# Error 415 from IAV Rest API - Get verbose error message

Tags: yodlee

I have been trying the Instant Account Verification using the REST api but have run into a couple issues. I receive an error 415(Problem Updating Account) when calling either the addTransferAccountForItem or  addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest api. I'm wondering if there is any way to get a more detailed error message to understand what I'm doing wrong when making these calls. The error message is being returned in XML format although it should be returned in JSON.

Here's an example snippet of how I'm making the addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest call. GDURL is a simple class that holds the url and concatenates all parameters into a string in format "param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value...".

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

The url I am using are:

addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequestURL=
baseUrl+jsonsdk/ExtendedInstantVerificationDataService/addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest/

addTransferAccountForItem=
baseUrl+jsonsdk/TransferAccountManagement/addTransferAccountForItem/

```
logger.info("Attempting to add item and start verification");
        try{
            GDURL iavUrl = new GDURL(restURL + addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequestURL);
            iavUrl.addParameter("cobSessionToken", cobrandSessionToken);
            iavUrl.addParameter("userSessionToken", userSessionToken);
            iavUrl.addParameter("contentServiceId", contentServiceId);
            iavUrl.addParameter("accountNumber", accountNumber);
            iavUrl.addParameter("routingNumber", routingNumber);
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields.enclosedType", "com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle");

            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].displayName", "UserID");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName", "IF_LOGIN");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].helpText", "4710");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].isEditable", "true");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].maxlength", "32");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].name", "LOGIN");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].size", "20");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].value", bankUsername);
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier", "LOGIN");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[0].valueMask", "LOGIN_FIELD");

            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].displayName", "Password");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName", "IF_PASSWORD");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].helpText", "11976");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].isEditable", "true");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].maxlength", "40");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].name", "PASSWORD");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].size", "20");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].value", bankPassword);
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier", "PASSWORD");
            iavUrl.addParameter("credentialFields[1].valueMask", "LOGIN_FIELD");

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) iavUrl.getURL().openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.connect();

            String s="";
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes(iavUrl.getParamString());

            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                while(bufferedReader.ready())
                    s+=bufferedReader.readLine()+"/n";

            }

            System.out.println("add item response: /n" + s);

        }catch(IOException e){
            logger.error("error occured", e);
        }
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I need help related to this question. I am not finding any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The 415(problem updating account) is an error thrown by Yodlee's data agent when it encounters an exception while trying to aggregate the account from end site. This particular error is thrown for situations where the end site terminates the session established by the data agent as the user might have already been logged in to the end site directly.

To know more about error code please refer this [document](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes)

Comment: "This particular error is thrown for situations where the end site terminates the session established by the data agent as the user might have already been logged in to the end site directly". 

Upon that assumption, I entered incorrect credential fields expecting a different error but still got the same error. Unfortunately, I was not able to get any further insight from the error codes document.

Comment: @shreyans Do you have any solution for that? This one is not working.