# Yodlee Call returning Error_Code 415 for addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest?

Tags: web-services, api, yodlee, callout

I need to call `addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest` to do Instant Account Verification using Yodlee IAV Rest APIs.

I am following this documentation and providing the data params that are given here:
[addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest](https://developer.yodlee.com/InstantAccountVerification/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_REST_API_Reference/addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest/)

But calling this APIs following the given documentation, I am getting this response from Yodlee APIs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Errors xmlns="http://namespace.yodlee.com/pfm/2009/Error">
    <Error>
        <errorCode>415</errorCode>
        <errorDetail>system_error</errorDetail>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

I have also visited this solution here but this is not helpful:

[Error 415 from IAV Rest API - Get verbose error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366439/error-415-from-iav-rest-api-get-verbose-error-message)

Any idea, how to go through this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing all the required parameter? please verify the parameters listed [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/InstantAccountVerification/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_REST_API_Reference/addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest).

This exception can come in many scenarios.

one such scenario where you can get this exception is when cobSessionToken parameter is not passed.

Also are you following the correct [flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/InstantAccountVerification/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_API_Flow/IAV_Data_Services_API_Flow)?

The exception 415(Problem Updating Account) is different than the error you have listed here.

Comment: You do not have permissions to view this page.

Comment: Please check now. The site was under maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a 415 error.  In my case, it was a special chars inserted and invisible on the editor.  Sometimes copy and paste from browser and into the editor introduce this special chars.

please view the details of my experience here.

[Yodlee REST API /authenticate/login returns 415 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579370/yodlee-rest-api-authenticate-login-returns-415-error)