# Yodlee REST API /authenticate/login returns 415 error

Tags: api, rest, authentication, yodlee

I have created a Yodlee developer account and with the sample provided
i am able to do a coblogin ... however if I now do a user login it
gives a 415 error.

I am referencing this info:
https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/login

This is the rest data i am sending to /authenticate/login
I am doing a POST and even sent in the header the application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Array
        (
            [cobSessionToken] => 08062013_0:70f264b74e053e595c3044e554aab5bda7c5d83be1a085f32dc1cd4c48b372dc2201a826f720d9821cf30d6966cc6eb05e7e02f83da19e60e38e21fbc9d59134
            [login] => sbMemnathaniel.j1
            [password] => sbMemnathaniel.j1#123
        )

This account works on the Test Drive.

Comment: I have downloaded the PHP sample code from yodlee site. http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Sample_Apps  
Cobrand Login Works but the Test User account login does not.
Anyone from yodlee tech support please clarify thIs issue?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much comparing the codes, i've found the culprit to the 415 error code.
There are special characters that are invisible to the editor.
I've caught the special chars that crept into my uRl by outputting all text sent for post into the browser.

These were the unwelcome chars  â€‹

So i have to cut the line of code and retype into the editor to clean up the invisible chars.

Answer (score 0):

415 is also triggered if you're not on the right IP address.